# Distributed package cannot find import

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

I'm trying to distribute [this code](https://github.com/EKami/kaggle-data-downloader) through git+pip . I was able to properly create the `setup.py` file for deployment but after installing the package with:

`https://github.com/EKami/kaggle-data-downloader`

Running this import gives me an error:

```
>>> from kaggle_data_downloader import KaggleDataDownloader
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Users/Ekami/Programs/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kaggle_data_downloader/KaggleDataDownloader.py", line 3, in <module>
    import utils
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

But with:

```
>>> import kaggle_data_downloader.utils
```

It works. It seems `KaggleDataDownloader` cannot find `kaggle_data_downloader.utils`. I think I missed something in the `setup.py` file. Any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: You're trying to use a Python 2 project on Python 3.

Comment: I am the one who created the project and I did it only with python 3. I don't get your point...

Comment: Your project is broken, then. You most likely tested it wrong, from within the `kaggle_data_downloader` folder.

Comment: Your `kaggle_data_downloader.KaggleDataDownloader` module is trying to import its sibling module `kaggle_data_downloader.util` as if it were a top-level `util` module. (Also, `KaggleDataDownloader` is a bad module name. Module names should be lowercase.)

Comment: This kind of bad module name does not prevent the whole thing from working. Look at the [code](https://github.com/EKami/kaggle-data-downloader/blob/master/kaggle_data_downloader/KaggleDataDownloader.py) I just do a simple `import utils` in there. How could it be broken? I tested it locally before deploying and it worked well. It is only when I install it through `pip` that the whole thing collapse. It must be related to the `setup.py` file, I just missed something there but I don't know what.

Comment: I know you just do `import utils`. `import utils` is **wrong**. The module is not `utils`; it is `kaggle_data_downloader.utils`.

Comment: `import utils` would only look for `kaggle_data_downloader.utils` on Python 2, which is why I thought this was a Python 2 project at first.

Comment: Oh okay. So how could I make it work as with Python 2? I mean I would like to keep the `import utils` in `KaggleDataDownloader` as if I replace this import with `import kaggle_data_downloader.utils` it's my local tests which won't work anymore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144882/discussion-between-e-kami-and-user2357112).